# Silverstripe File onAfterUpload method not called

Tags: php, silverstripe

I have an extension to File added with

```
Object::add_extension('File', 'MyFileDecorator');
```

I can confirm that the extension class is being created and that extending methods `onBeforeWrite` is working fine.

However, I am never seeing an extended `onAfterUpload` being called, despite the documentation claiming it should be called when the file has been uploaded.

I have tried using `FileIFrameField`, `FileUploadField` (from uploadify) and various data object manager classes, all to no avail.

Looking through `FileIFrameField`, it looks like there's no call to `onAfterUpload` so I guess my question is whether there's a field I could use that does call that method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, doesn't look like it does get called. Uncle cheese's FileAttachmentField which is part of the kick assets module uses it. It's a nice file uploader But I believe it only works in the cms. Are you hoping to implement this in the cms or frontend?

https://github.com/unclecheese/KickAssets

Another option would be making use of the onAfterWrite method

Comment: The aim is to get the file itself uploaded (mirrored) to S3 so I'm trying to avoid the onAfterWrite to avoid issues if other image data is saved. Thanks for the info on the alternative. It will be in the CMS so should be good.

Comment: Oh right, you could also check out the uploadify module, it has S3 stuff built in ;)

Comment: In the end we decided the S3 mirroring wasn't the best plan anyway and are now doing direct S3 uploads (skipping PHP altogether) using Uploadify. Thanks for your guidance, though.

Comment: Yeah the double upload is a bit of a hassle, especially for large files. No probs ;)